# Is ASP.NET Core, Microsoft.FeatureManagement <feature> TagHelper is badly designed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I made such steps:

1. `Install-Package Microsoft.FeatureManagement.AspNetCore`
2. put in .cshtml page:

```
<feature name="IsDoomsday">you may type format c:</feature>
```

3. added in the Startup.cs

```
services.AddFeatureManagement();
```

4. in appsettings.json

```
{
  "FeatureManagement": { "IsDoomsday": false }
}
```

and want **"you may type format c:"** string to be displayed **only** if feature **IsDoomsday** is enabled. Obviously I didn't configured something properly and my latest Firefox 78.0.2 unexpectedly shows **"you may type format c:"** and there is:
`<feature name="IsDoomsday">you may type format c:</feature>`
in the guts of generated html.

How it could be, that the output of such critical feature may depend on misconfiguration and leak to the user, is it the design failue of a **<feature>**?

(weak) **FIX**: do not miss the following in the views hierarchy:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.FeatureManagement.AspNetCore
```

(PS: I ended up switching to @if in .cshtml page)

```
@if (await FeatureManager.IsEnabledAsync("IsDoomsday"))
{
<text>you may type format c:</text>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than claiming that some feature/library is badly designed, first read the documentation, understand how it works and, if needed, look at a tutorial to know how to use it. You can find a tutorial here: [Quickstart: Add feature flags to an ASP.NET Core app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-feature-flag-aspnet-core?tabs=core3x).

The following works perfectly fine, explanation added by me:

1. Install the NuGet package `Microsoft.FeatureManagement.AspNetCore` - contains the functionality wanted
2. Add a feature to your appsettings.json or appsettings.{environment}.json file. The package reads from the built configuration. Updated file from new project:

   ```
    {
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft": "Warning",
          "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
      },
      "FeatureManagement": {
        "IsDoomsday": true
      }
    }
   ```
3. Register the services needed by the package. For example, you can use the pre-configured IConfiguration:

   ```
   services.AddFeatureManagement();
   ```
4. Enable the FeatureTagHelper by registering it, for example, in `_ViewImports.cshtml`:

   ```
   @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.FeatureManagement.AspNetCore
   ```
5. Use the tag helper wherever you want to:

   ```
   <feature name="IsDoomsday">Hello doomsday</feature>
   ```

You can play around with `"IsDoomsday": true | "IsDoomsday": false` and see that it renders or doesn't render the feature, as expected.

Comment: The point is that the correct behavior of <feature> TagHelper can't depend on a web designer accidentally deleting @addTagHelper in some UI page.

Comment: Of course it can @tivadj - you deleted the code that makes the tag helper be something else than just plain HTML. That's exactly how TagHelpers are designed in ASP.NET Core

Comment: <feature> TagHelper brings security risks and thus must be removed from the library immediately.

Comment: @tivadj Or you could just not use a functionality you don't understand

Comment: do you understand that a change in site's UI (in _ViewImports.cshtml) shouldn't lead to exposure of critical site' functionality?

Comment: @tivadj And should be checked through Pull Requests in the exact same way all other critical pieces of code or configuration should be checked through proper Pull Requests. What happens if you remove an `[Authorize]` from a Controller? Oops, you don't need to log-in anymore, are you also going to remove that functionality?

Comment: I expect changes in .cs files to be made by programmers, not web-designers.

Comment: @tivadj And I expect web designers working with server-side code to understand the framework they are using. Otherwise, don't give them Razor, give them HTML files.